# Does libc++.so use libc.so or libc++.so stand-alone?

Tags: android, c++, c

In android /system/lib, I see  both libc++ and libc are present. I understand that C++ also includes C. So, If I call functions like printf, scanf, malloc... from which library these are taken to be executed? From libc.so or libc++.so?

Recently I had to investigate one memory leak issue, so I’m using libc.debug.malloc 1 approach.

I did,

1. Pushed libc_malloc_debug_leak.so to /system/lib
2. and shell
3. su
4. setprop libc.debug.malloc 1
5. stop
6. start
7. Run my android app which is calling c++ code via JNI. I intentionally leaked memory allocated by malloc.

Still I am not getting leak information in logs.

If the approach works only for libc and my app uses only libc++, the approach not showing leak information in logs is correct.

Please help me understand which library is used by android apps having native cpp code, libc++ or libc? And also libc++ has any dependency on libc?

Comment: The `ldd` tool can probably answer your question.

Comment: You can figure this out yourself. There tools like nm or objdump that let you see which symbols are in which shared library.

Comment: malloc debugging is built in see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/malloc_debug/README.md

Comment: printf, scanf, malloc are defined in libc. The list of symbol either defined or used in a library can be retrieved using `nm`. For example `nm libc.so.6` (or with the right libc version number) will show a table where each line is (address  type  symbol): "2398412 T malloc". The T means it is defined in libc. If you do `nm libc++.so.x` you may see "439825098 U malloc" which means libc++ use malloc, but does not define it.